# jQuery: Converting each function to for loop

Tags: javascript, for-loop, jquery

I recently had received the help of you great people on stackoverflow to help me move a background image the appropriate distance on a mouseover event. This works great, but the problem is that I'm concerned how optimal it is using the each function.

I'm hoping I can get a brief explanation on how to convert this particular code to a for loop as I'm interested in the optimization benefits, but I'm not quite understanding the difference in syntax for how to convert it to a for loop.

```
var xPosition = -195;
$('div.style-swatches ul li').each(function(){
    $(this).mouseenter(function(){
        $(this).closest('div.chip-style').find('div.chip-preview').css("background-position", (xPosition - ($(this).index() * 195)) + "px 0");
    });
});
```

Comment: For someone who doesn't understand enough to make the conversion, you sound terribly sure that converting this to a loop will "optimize" it.

Comment: You're technically already using a for loop; jQuery is just doing it for you.

Comment: The performance gain is going to be marginal if any at all since this is essentially what `jQuery` is doing for you

Comment: For the record, what you should do here is just `$('div.style-swatches ul li').mouseenter(function() { ... })`. There's no need for `each` at all.

Comment: [Here is jQuery's implementation of $.each](https://github.com/jquery/jquery/blob/master/src/core.js#L316) for anyone who wants to know. I was curious if they had implemented it using [Array.prototype.forEach](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/forEach) where possible.

Comment: @Jon I'd argue it would be even better to _delegate_ that to a single handler, avoiding the whole mess altogether.

Comment: @Mathletics: Sure thing. And while we 're at it, perhaps that selector could be tightened up? Both of the above would be legitimate optimization.

Comment: Thanks Jon. I would have marked your second response there as the answer if I could, but Roko below answered with the same. I must have asked my question wrong as I'm not terribly sure of anything in regards to jQuery efficiency... not yet anyways. I simply ran across that "optimization" option through several blogs on the topic. =)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Simply don't use the `.each()`

[Demo fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/zPtr6/5/)

```
$("div.style-swatches li").mouseenter(function() {
     $(this).closest('div.chip-style').find('div.chip-preview').css("background-position", (xPosition - ($(this).index() * 195)) + "px 0");
});
```

Comment: Nice catch, i keep forgetting that you can assign directly and jQuery loops internally. Also IIRR jQuery uses loop unrolling/unwinding under the cover for speed optimizations

Answer (score 2):

Never optimize without benchmarks. First profile your code, collect *real* data, see what function call *really* takes up a lot of time/memory and *then* optimize the discovered performance bottlenecks.

In your particular case, I'd expect the DOM queries to take a few orders of magnitude more time than the loop construct. You could think about simplifying your CSS queries (e.g. changing `div.style-swatches ul li` to `.style-swatches li` if appropriate), use the native DOM instead of wrapping everything in a jQuery object,...

As some other answers already pointed out, you don't actually *need* the loop at all, as `.mouseenter()` already does that (and uses a `.each()` loop internally).

Comment: This is great advice. Thank you for sharing it and expanding on simplifying the CSS query. Much appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

Any selection uses a for loop under the covers. Basically, any time you see $(".css-selector") think, "For all matching elements". In your code the .each(...) just makes the process more explicit.

If you really wanted to break this out into a for loop, you could use your selector and then index the elements directly, a la:

```
var elems = $('div.style-swatches ul li');
for (var i = 0; i < elems.length; ++i){
  $(elems[i]).mouseenter(function(){
        $(this).closest('div.chip-style').find('div.chip-preview').css("background-position", (xPosition - ($(this).index() * 195)) + "px 0");
    });

}
```

But again, since jQuery already does this itself, it's doubtful you'll see any beneficial performance impact.

Answer (score 0):

The jquery selector returns an array. You can just iterate on it

```
var xPosition = -195;
var elements = $('div.style-swatches ul li');
for(var i = 0; i < elements.length; i++) {
    $(elements[i]).mouseenter(function() {
        $(this).closest('div.chip-style').find('div.chip-preview').css("background-position", (xPosition - ($(this).index() * 195)) + "px 0");
    });
}
```

Answer (score 0):

$('div.style-swatches ul li') returns and array of items ..just loop it

```
var xPosition = -195;
var items     = $('div.style-swatches ul li');

for (var i = 0, l = items.length; i < l; i++) {
    $(items[i]).mouseenter(function(){
        $(items[i]).closest('div.chip-style').find('div.chip-preview').css("background-position", (xPosition - ($(items[i]).index() * 195)) + "px 0");
    });
}
```